# How to only install versions of packages that were made under a specific R release?

Tags: r, package, snapshot, revolution-r, reproducible-research

I use the Revolution R Enterprise distribution that is built upon R 3.2.2. Hence, I have an interest in only employing package versions that are based on this R release as well. Checking packages like 'checkpoint' or the Revolution MRAN page, I only found ways to access snapshots of CRAN datewise. Is there a way to install the most recent package versions still compatible with a certain R release?

Comment: You mean like [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)?

Comment: Does packrat enable me to say 'install all package versions necessary for the project that are compatible with R 3.2.2'? If yes, then indeed packrat is what I need. I have heard of it before, but shied away from it since peers of mine described it as buggy.

Comment: I don't think you can get off that easy, but perhaps you could manually build the file that is read by `restore` and have everything set up as if migrating. See [walkthrough](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/walkthrough.html) for more info.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915907/how-do-different-versions-of-r-manage-to-seemingly-automatically-download-differ) might help

Answer (score 2):

I found a heuristical solution to my own problem:

1. Find out about the release date of the stable R version *succeeding* your working version.
2. Set up an R script that calls all the packages you need for your project via individual `library()` or `require()` calls.
3. Use `checkpoint(release date minus at least one day)` to automatically create a project specific library which is in harmony with your working R version.

Step 2 is a failsafe way to ensure detection of all necessary packages. I called them by `sapply(package.list, require)`, which `checkpoint()` was not able to handle. A possible caveat against this solution might be that it possibly does not deliver the very last version of a package which is still compatible with your older R version. Alternatively, to be very sure, instead of the stable release one could use the prerelease date to be absolutely sure about compatibility.