# How to download package and dependencies for given R version?

Tags: r, package

I am working in a computer without admin rights. The R version installed is 3.4.4. The IT administrator sees no prospect in upgrading R.

I need to install a package and its dependencies manually (I know how to do this). To download the packages and dependencies, I use the code below (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15650828/3585386)), which works fine:

```
getPackages <- function(packs){
  packages <- unlist(
    tools::package_dependencies(packs, available.packages(), which=c("Depends", "Imports"), recursive=TRUE)
  )
  packages <- union(packs, packages)
  packages
}

packages <- getPackages(c("gmm"))

download.packages(packages, destdir="/home/<user>/Downloads/", type="win.binary")
```

The only problem is that **it will download the latest version of every package**. Is there a way I can do the above, but specifying an R version? The `package_dependencies()` function seems to contain not such option. There is a package called `miniCRAN` ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/)) which has functions to check dependencies accepting the option of `Rversion`, but only allowing for two digits (e.g. 3.1, 3.2, etc). I need the three digit one.

Comment: Is there a package where a three digit version number match is required? What's wrong with minicran when you use version 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can first see which is the suitable version of the package for your R and then using:

```
install_version("gmm", version = "0.x.x", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Sure, but this involves the manual task of going to the website of every package I want. I'm looking for an automatic way to do this. The information must somewhat be built-in somewhere.

Comment: Hi luchonacho, I don't think there is an automatic way to do this. Here was described an heuristic solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890269/how-to-only-install-versions-of-packages-that-were-made-under-a-specific-r-relea], it might help